# method not suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, error-handling

I get the error Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry point.
I want to use the method UploadFileToBlobStorage in the main method.

Here is my main method:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args,BlobContainerClient containerClient)
{
    _ = CreateBlobClientContainerAsync();

    _ = UploadFileToBlobStorage(containerClient);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and here is the UploadFileToBlobStorage method:

```
public static async Task<int> UploadFileToBlobStorage(BlobContainerClient containerClient)
{
    // Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
    string localPath = "./data/";
    string fileName = "perfblob" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

    // Write text to the file
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Blob Upload!");

    // Get a reference to a blob
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

    Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

    // Upload data from the local file
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(localFilePath, true);

    return 200;
}
```

Comment: could you share how you executing Main method? how you passing containerClient parameter to method please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Main method doesn't have a valid code signature, you have to remove this argument "BlobContainerClient containerClient"

Comment: okay. how do i use UploadFileToBlobStorage in my Main?

Comment: the main method can have one argument only args  =>  Main(string[] args),

Comment: ,BlobContainerClient containerClient  have you tried to define it as a field

Comment: how exactly would I do that?